# Limit the scope of a search to a page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, search-scope, sharepoint-search

I have a Discussion Board and in each item, which is in the flat view, I have set up a search box (EDIT: as a web part in the Flat View of that item) to search only that particular page(i.e) responses of that particular item. However, I am unable to find any query to do that. The best I have done, is limit the search to that particular Discussion Board List. Is it possible to limit the query (EDIT: in the Search Results) to just that view page?

Answer (score 0):

in such cases i always recommend to use the browser-search

EDIT: 
If you use the Flat View you can use the list search:

1. Navigate to the list view
2. Edit Page
3. Edit List View Webpart (Discussion Board)
4. Miscellaneous --> Display Search Box

This list search only returns results of the current visible item in your list view.

Comment: Display search box is checked, in the Discussion Board's Flat View. However, no new search box appears.

Comment: what do you mean with "new" search box? this inline search is only a little input field beside the view selection

Comment: I had misunderstood. I was able to get the search box you mentioned, but only when I changed the view to Management View. But I want to retain the Subject View, while searching the messages. Is there any way for that?

Comment: now I can't follow any more....
Description: Flat View; 
Comment: Management View / Subject View 
?!?!?!

Comment: In Flat View (ie /Flat.aspx), I get the discussion in the form of one message after the other. That is Flat View, I presume. 
And in this view, the Display Search Box is selected. But, no inline text box appears.
Sorry for the above confusion, regarding Views.